# Pandas counting number of rows based on data of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataset with format similar to this :-

```
Name      Sex     Survived      random_cols . . . .

Akshit    Male        1           rand_val   .......

Hema      Female      0           .................

Rekha      Female     1           .................
.
.
.
```

I want to count the number of `Male` and `Female` who `Survived` i.e have value `1` for the `Survived` column. I can do this easily with a naive approach of using counter but I was wondering if there is a way to do this in more efficient way with few lesser lines of code using `pandas`

```
m = 0
f = 0
for i in range(len(train_data['Sex'])):
    if train_data['Sex'][i] == 'male' and train_data['Survived'][i] == 1:
        m = m + 1
    
    if train_data['Sex'][i] == 'female' and train_data['Survived'][i] == 1:
        f = f + 1

print(m)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)

```
train_data.value_counts(subset=['Sex', 'Survived'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing to filter by the `Survived` column to get only survived rows then `value_counts` on `Sex` column:

```py
s = df[df['Survived'].eq(1)].value_counts(subset=['Sex'])
```

```
print(s)

Sex
Female    1
Male      1
dtype: int64
```

The return value is a pandas Series, you can access its value with

```py
s['Male']
s['Female']
```